# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null - JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Having trouble getting rid of this console error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null", my understanding of reading a few other stack overflow articles is that the JS file is running before the html is done loading. I've moved the  right before the closing  in the index file and have tried deferring the JS file by doing:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {     
   // copy code here
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>API Explorer</title>
        <script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="./people.html">People</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1>API Explorer</h1>
        <div id="data-container">
            <div id="people"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

scripts.js:

```
function getDataName(url, div) {
    try {
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => showDataName(data.results, div))
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error("Error: " + error)
    }
}


showDataName = (dataObjects, div) => {
    const dataDiv = document.querySelector(div)
    dataObjects.forEach(dataObject => {
        const dataElement = document.createElement('p')
        dataElement.innerText= `Name: ${dataObject.name}`
        dataDiv.append(dataElement)
    })

}

getDataName('https://swapi.dev/api/people/', '#people')
```

Comment: It says `// copy code here`... so did you?

Answer (score 1):

In `showDataName`, you defined `dataDiv` with a querySelector, but you didn't wrap the selector with parenthesis, so it returns `null`.

So, line 13 of script.js should be `const dataDiv = document.querySelector("div")`.

Also, you should select it as `#data-container` instead of `div` because if you add another div in front of it, it will select that instead.

```
const dataDiv = document.querySelector("#data-container")
```

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot, thank you so much for pointing this out. This worked!

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `div` there is the second parameter that is passed to `showDataName()`. Which it received when called from `getDataName()`, to which its value is also passed as the second parameter. The value of `div` is `'#people'` as you can see in the last line. [It should work just fine like that](https://jsfiddle.net/6r2p9vtn/).